# How to configure another placement for ~/.drush/cache?

Tags: cache, drupal

I have multiple Drupal 8 applications (sites) inside one hosting (under one `$HOME` directory). Every site has its own Drush Commandline Tool 9.x in `site_N_directory/bin/drush` and `site_N_directory/vendor/drush/`.

I observed recently, that when I run more drushes in parallel, they influence each other, because they use one common `~/.drush/cache` directory.

How can I configure Drush to use specific cache directory under `site_N_directory/` instead of `~/.drush/cache`?